# PHP exec() function - post extended

Tags: php, exec

thanks all of you for patiently answering my question "About exec() function in PHP: [About exec() function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271259/about-exec-function-in-php)", it has given me an idea of how this works and so. Lots of them pointed the syntax error, my pardon forgot to include the quotes.

Actually I have got a requirement in normal conditions the customer has the .exe file which he needs to normally run from command prompt, where he needs to include the path for the license and config files manually, so that application is valid for installation.

Now he wants a php script where he will enter the web page with his valid login details and with the click of link he should be able to run the .exe file to install the software on his machine. Including the license and config file is my job which I have been working on, on the other hand I am still not clear that this is really possible to run the .exe file on the clients machine when the script runs on the php remote server. What can be the other alternatives to accomplish this. Can anyone clear my doubts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About exec() function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271259/about-exec-function-in-php)

Comment: don't know of any way a *PHP* script on the server could execute anything on a clients machine, at least not without the help of something else. I think you have to think in the direction of "Java applet".

Comment: Sure <a href="/path/to/somefile.exe"> Download </a>

Comment: Ofcourse with java applet you can do it.It will not easy to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** run anything on the client machine from a PHP script running on the **server**. It's impossible. What you **can** do is create an archive (e.g. ZIP) that contains the executable file, the license file and the configuration. Then you can offer this archive to the user as download. After extracting the archive on his machine he then would be able to execute the application.

Other possibilities to execute something on the client machine would be a Java applet or a Flash application. Those are subject to a lot of security restrictions though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

- 1.Save settings to file
- 2.Compact programm to archive with setting file &&  license
- 3.Download archive

Answer (score 0):

PHP is on the server, the server generates HTML/JS/CSS. The PHP process ends before the web page is displayed to the user.

There's no way, and a VERY VERY good reason why this can not or will never be able to be done.

And why would you want to run an .exe file on someone's computer other than malicious reasons?

You're on the Web, sell subscription, what licensing are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to actually execute a program on the client machine directly from PHP. The best you can hope to achieve is to provide a download for the executable file and then the client can execute it manually. You could provide an archive file with the installation executable and config/license file(s), but the client would still have to execute the file manually.

You could potentially use client-side technologies such as Flash, Java or ActiveX to accomplish this, but this is not a simple task and requires fairly intimate knowledge of the languages on which these technologies are based.

If the file was an MSI, it would be theoretically possible to allow the server to remotely install it on the client machine, however there are some barriers to this:

- You need a fully fledged Windows domain for this, and both the server and client machines would have to be members of that domain. There is no way around this.
- You would most likely need to know the NetBIOS name of the client machine, and there is AFAIK no 100% reliable way to determine this from PHP.
- Your PHP instance would need to be running under an account that has administrative privileges in the domain. This is unlikely to be the case at the moment, and it is not a very good idea to run like this anyway.